# How To Get Input Value That Saved Before

Tags: jquery, input, keyup

I have the following function:

```
$(function () {
    $('#phone-number').keyup(function(){
        var pnumber=$(this).val();
        $('.phone-number').text(pnumber)
    });
});
```

I can get the value after keyup event but I have problem with the value that is saved in input text when user double clicks on input.
By the way `#phone-number` is a input type text
and `.phone-number` is a Div

Comment: `but i have problem with the value that saved in input when user double click on input.` ?

Comment: here is a fiddle what is wrong with double click? http://jsfiddle.net/twp3o217/

Comment: i want to get the value of input in 2 way after keyup and when value is saved in input after user double click and used it when its saved keyup dosent work

Comment: why would user double click an input type text? who does that?is that what you mean?please explain a bit more.\

Comment: this input is a login form that get phone number and generate a code every time user want to login should fill his/her phone number.when user do this action before his/her phone number was saved in input that he/she dose not need to fill in again he/she can do this action with mouse no need for keyboard.sorry for my bad language

Comment: are you looking for this?i added an initial value then called the change event manually is this what you mean?no need to double click the input box because no one double clicks the input text user just type in input text. http://jsfiddle.net/twp3o217/2/

Comment: yeah that what im looking for tank you so much

Comment: I added it as answer please check if it helped for future reference

Comment: yeah i checked it and it workes for me

Comment: I am glad it works. i put it as answer if you may check the check so that it will become answered questions for future reference.happy coding !

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#phone-number').val('78908');
$('#phone-number').on("keyup change", function () {
    var pnumber = $(this).val();
    $('.phone-number').text(pnumber)
});
$('#phone-number').change();
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/twp3o217/2/)

are you looking for this?i added an initial value then called the change event manually is this what you mean?no need to double click the input box because no one double clicks the input text user just type in input text